# How do I handle calling windows azure mobile services and detecting no connection ?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, connection, azure-mobile-services

I have the code for using HttpClient below but now I want to use Windows Azure Mobiles Services.. My app was not published because they said I am not checking for a connection.. What is a simple way to do this ?

```
   private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();

        //try to ping service before getting high scores
        try
        {
            SetProgressIndicator(true);
            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Loading...";

            GetHighScores(); //?????????

          //  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
          //  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://punkoutersoftware.azurewebsites.net/api/drunkmeterscore");
          //  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            SetProgressIndicator(false);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("High Scores not available at the moment");
        }

    }

    private async void GetHighScores()
    {
        try
        {
            scores = await scoreTable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToCollectionAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error loading items", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        ListItems.ItemsSource = scores;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like and odd problem, never heard of that. Maybe try microsoft forum and post answer here. Because the try and catch method is what I usually use.

Comment: I think they're telling you to check for a network connection upon startup?  i.e. if you check to see if you *can* used HttpClient before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the verification process tests with an unresponsive Azure Mobile Services.  They're likely testing with no data connection.  You can check for a data connection before doing any operation that might need a data connection like this:

```
if(!DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
{
   // inform user to get a data connection
}
```